# php access to stocktwits api

Tags: php, stocktwits

Is there anybody that succeeded in calling API methods from within a PHP script?

What I'm bassicaly trying to do is use my ST account to let a PHP script post on my behalf.

I got stuck with the authentication. I use the oauth_client.php class but can't seem to get it to work. When trying to do the same on twitter, I got it working in a whim.

I would appreciate a fully working php code example very much as the API documentation isn't very clear. It just mentions the protocol. But I fure this is more of a configuration problem.

Comment: you're asking the equivalent of "did anyone succeed in making a telephone call?". API is a generic term. Succeeding in making a call to (say) the Facebook API has absolutely no relation in making a call to the PayPal API, except they both generally involve the same communications techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is in javascript, I found this section of code at the bottom of this link to be incredibly helpful. While I don't know enough php to find a working example, I hope this helps:

http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/signin

This allows you to open a window, get a request from Stocktwits, then verify that you actually did. After struggling a bit with the same sort of issue, I found this and it worked instantly and allowed me to easily call APIs by mirroring the style.